# eval_metric of XGBoost // ML model in general

Tags: machine-learning-model, xgboost, model-evaluations, parameter, rmse

Say I am using Xgboost on a binary classification task. eval_metric  is one of the model parameter. How should I think about the impact of using different eval_metric(e.g rmse/mae/logloss) in general? Is there a guide on using each of them under different scenario?

Answer (score 1):

Which metric to choose is not related to the model, but to the problem to be solved. If you are unsure, go back and think about the objective - *why* we need to build the model, and *what* the model needs to achieve. Base on this understanding we then pick a metric, or craft our own.